# Extract first 3 characters from Json response using JMeter Json Extractor

Tags: jmeter

{
"Profiles": [{
"name": "Anil",
"Country": "INDIA"
}, {
"name": "Sunil",
"Country": "EURO"
}
]
}

Using JSon Extractor, I am able to extract country (INDIA Or EURO) with JSonPathExpression: $..Country.
How can I extract only first 3 characters of country(i.e IND or EUR) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps:

1. For example if you want to get the `Country` for `Anil` you can do this as:

   ```
   $.Profiles.[?(@.name == 'Anil')].Country
   ```

   full [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) just in case:

   [image]
2. Next you can extract first 3 letters using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) like:

   [image]

   [image]

   textual representation of the regular expression:

   ```
   (^.{0,3})
   ```